# How to load different views with different jquery plugins/libraries rendered on it in angular2 by using routers?

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-plugins, angular2-routing

static view are easy to render in routing in angular2.But how to show dynamic views by rendering jquery plugins or libraries on them?

app.routing.ts:

```
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { OwnComponent } from './own.component';
    import { Own1Component } from './own1.component';
    import { Own2Component } from './own2.component';
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
       { path: 'own1', component: Own1Component },
      { path: 'own2', component: Own2Component },

      { path: '', component: OwnComponent },
      { path: '**', component: AppComponent }
    ];

    export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

    ];

    export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

own.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: '<h1>From own on default</h1>'
})
export class OwnComponent { }
```

own1.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'flot.html',
})
export class Own1Component {}
```

own2.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'morris.html',
})
export class Own2Component { }
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Now,here,morris.html and flot.html requires jquery plugins to load their stuff. so,i've tried all stuff like:
including jquery libraries in flot.html,morris.html,index.html,app.component.html

But none of them worked.
And,putting angular2 removes script tag from morris.html and flot.html i don't know why.
so i am confused.and i want them to load specific js for specific routes.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and where you're stuck.

Comment: @GunterZochbauer i have just include that

Comment: There should be enough questions with answer about how to use jQuery with Angular2 here already.

Comment: yeah it's given but it's only for few lines of code.And here i wanna load whole plugin.

Comment: I don't use jQuery. Maybe someone else can help.